# Binary tree - finding K smallest elements

Tags: c

Any idea how to do this? Recursively and in-order …

```
void print_lowest(Tree* root, compare_func compare, print_func print) {
    int k, i; int min, repeat;
    printf("\nEnter number of k: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &k) == 1);
    min = root->key;
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        repeat = root->key;//reset value
        find_min(root, &min, repeat, compare);
        print(min);
    }
}

void find_min(Tree* root, int* min, int repeat, compare_func compare) {

    if (root != NULL) {
        find_min(root->left, min, repeat, compare);
        if (compare(root->key, repeat)==1) {//if rootkey<repeat
            if(*min != root->key)
            *min = root->key;
            repeat = *min;
        }
        find_min(root->right, min, repeat, compare);
    }
    return;
}
```

I tried this but obviously doesn't work; any other good ideas or algorithms?
For example this tree (https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/binary-tree.png).
I want the 3 smallest elements, which are 1, 3, 4.

```
                 8
                 |
      +----------+-----------+
      |                      |
      3                      10
      |                      |
 +----+----+                 +------+
 |         |                        |
 1         6                        14
           |                        |
       +---+---+                +---+
       |       |                |
       4       7                13
```

<sup>*ASCII-art more or less equivalent to image.*</sup>

Comment: Hint: 1. In-order traversal will get you ascending order of elements. 2.  Need to pass a reference of a count and increment as you recursively visit the nodes. Once the visited node is `k` print it.

Comment: @TruthSeeker in order traversal will always get me ascending order?

Comment: Yes, if the tree is BST inorder traversal will give the ascending order. (Left node< parent node < right node)

Comment: Don't mix algorithmic code with I/O — it makes a mess.  You have `if (scanf("%d", &k) == 1);` — that's paying lip service only to error checking because you ignore the error and continue as if nothing has gone wrong.  Yes, I/O is messy; that's why you segregate it.  It also means that the algorithmic code is more easily reused.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code which is an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  It creates the tree shown in the question.  It prints an appropriate answer — the elements `1`, `3`, `4`.  It's a fairly direct implementation of the suggestions made by [TruthSeeker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4139593/truthseeker) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59832999/binary-tree-finding-ks-smallest-elements#comment105802024_59832999), but I had the same algorithm in mind without reading that comment.

```
/* SO 5983-2999 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include "stderr.h"

typedef struct Tree
{
    int key;
    struct Tree *left;
    struct Tree *right;
} Tree;

typedef void (*Printer)(const Tree *node);

static void bst_print_k_smallest(Tree *tree, int k, int *count, Printer print)
{
    if (tree->left != 0)
        bst_print_k_smallest(tree->left, k, count, print);
    if (*count < k)
    {
        (*count)++;
        print(tree);
    }
    if (*count < k && tree->right != 0)
        bst_print_k_smallest(tree->right, k, count, print);
}

static void bst_print_node(const Tree *node)
{
    if (node != 0)
    {
        printf("Node: 0x%.12" PRIXPTR " - key %3d; left = 0x%.12" PRIXPTR
               ", right = 0x%.12" PRIXPTR "\n",
               (uintptr_t)node, node->key, (uintptr_t)node->left,
               (uintptr_t)node->right);
    }
}

static Tree *bst_newnode(int key)
{
    Tree *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if (node == 0)
        err_syserr("failed to allocate %zu bytes of memory: ", sizeof(*node));
    node->key = key;
    node->left = node->right = 0;
    return node;
}

static Tree *bst_insert(Tree *root, int key)
{
    if (root == NULL)
        root = bst_newnode(key);
    else if (key < root->key)
        root->left = bst_insert(root->left, key);
    else if (key > root->key)
        root->right = bst_insert(root->right, key);
    /* else Repeat - ignore */
    return root;
}

static void bst_free(Tree *tree)
{
    if (tree != 0)
    {
        bst_free(tree->left);
        bst_free(tree->right);
        free(tree);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc > 0)
        err_setarg0(argv[0]);

    Tree *root = NULL;
    root = bst_insert(root,  8);
    root = bst_insert(root,  3);
    root = bst_insert(root, 10);
    root = bst_insert(root,  1);
    root = bst_insert(root,  6);
    root = bst_insert(root, 14);
    root = bst_insert(root,  4);
    root = bst_insert(root,  7);
    root = bst_insert(root, 13);

    int count = 0;
    bst_print_k_smallest(root, 3, &count, bst_print_node);

    bst_free(root);

    return 0;
}
```

The print function works around some issues with `%p` — the output isn't as neatly aligned for null pointers if you use raw `%p` so I specify the exact hex format I want and use `<inttypes.h>` and the `uintptr_t` type to get the result I want.  I use 12 digits because that's most appropriate on a (64-bit) Mac.  If you format to 16 digits, the addresses normally have the leading 4 bytes as zeros (which is dreadfully unexciting).  [YMMV](https://www.acronymfinder.com/YMMV.html) — tweak to suit your environment (e.g. use `8` instead of `12` if you're using a 32-bit build).  You could even define a macro to avoid repeating yourself three times.

The code above does use some code that is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.  The `err_*()` functions greatly simplify error reporting, which is why I wrote them and use them.

I specify all functions except `main()` with the keyword `static` because there's only a single source file, so there's no need for the functions to be visible outside this file.  If the functions were to be created in a separate source file, there'd be a header that would be included by both the source file that defined the functions and also by the source files that use the functions.  The header ensures that the definition and use of the functions are consistent, reducing the number of bugs due to inconsistency.

Sample output (source code `bst41.c` compiled to produce `bst41`):

```
$ make bst41 && bst41
gcc -O3 -g -I./inc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -L./lib bst41.c -lsoq -o bst41
Node: 0x7FAC29402AF0 - key   1; left = 0x000000000000, right = 0x000000000000
Node: 0x7FAC29402AB0 - key   3; left = 0x7FAC29402AF0, right = 0x7FAC29402B10
Node: 0x7FAC29402B50 - key   4; left = 0x000000000000, right = 0x000000000000
$
```

If you juggle the argument from 3 to 9, you get output like:

```
Node: 0x7FDC90402AF0 - key   1; left = 0x000000000000, right = 0x000000000000
Node: 0x7FDC90402AB0 - key   3; left = 0x7FDC90402AF0, right = 0x7FDC90402B10
Node: 0x7FDC90402B50 - key   4; left = 0x000000000000, right = 0x000000000000
Node: 0x7FDC90402B10 - key   6; left = 0x7FDC90402B50, right = 0x7FDC90402B70
Node: 0x7FDC90402B70 - key   7; left = 0x000000000000, right = 0x000000000000
Node: 0x7FDC90400690 - key   8; left = 0x7FDC90402AB0, right = 0x7FDC90402AD0
Node: 0x7FDC90402AD0 - key  10; left = 0x000000000000, right = 0x7FDC90402B30
Node: 0x7FDC90402B90 - key  13; left = 0x000000000000, right = 0x000000000000
Node: 0x7FDC90402B30 - key  14; left = 0x7FDC90402B90, right = 0x000000000000
```

If you want to be sure you printed as many values as you requested, check `count` in the `main()` (or calling) function.  If it is smaller than the `k` value, then there weren't enough nodes to print `k` values.

Tested on a MacBook Pro (still) running macOS Mojave 10.14.6 with GCC 9.2.0 and XCode 11.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

For any given Binary Search Tree in-order traversal will always gives ascending ordered element. In simple way in-order traversal is to visit first left node then root node then right node.

Consider below example which will have in-ordered traversal as **D B E A F C G**

```
       A
     /    \
    B      C
   / \    /  \
  D   E  F    G
```

Simple implementation would look like this,

```
void PrintLowestK(Tree* root, int*count, int k)
{
    if((!root)||(*count>=k)) //check whether node is not a null and already K-elements have been printed 
        return;

    PrintLowestK(root->left,count,k);//travel to the left of root

    if(*count <k){ //skewed tree or k present left side of the tree
        (*count)++;
        printf("%d ",root->key);       //print node
    }
    PrintLowestK(root->right,count,k); //travel right side of the node
}
```

Function has to be called like below,

```
int count = 0;
int k =3; //number of element to be printed 
PrintLowestK(root, &count, k);
```